# Программа, создающая php код картинки

Tags: gd, php

Есть ли программа, в которой можно создать картинку и она выдаст её php код. А то наклон текста, позиция - подгонять циферки - очень нудно(

ps А как сделать текст загнутым под определённым радиусом в php на картинке?

Comment: Ты понял что написал?

Comment: Да, а что-то не понятно?

Comment: ***создать картинку и получить её PHP код *** это как-то бредово.

вот наоборот еще куда не шло, а вот чтобы какая-то программа сама писала PHP код - не встречал.

Теперь нужно взять, сесть и правильно написать вопрос с входными и выходными данными.

Comment: Ну а загнуть текст возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ну а загнуть текст возможно?

Создать бит-маску текста, загнуть аркой и на картинку отпечатать попиксельно)

А вообще вот вам [примерчик](http://alex-tech-adventures.com/development/php/72-speedometer-style-text-curved-around-a-semicircle-using-php-with-gd-and-some-calculus.html), разбирайтесь

PS: php-кода картинки не существует, это bmp - строка байтов длиной `$width*$height*$colorDepth`.

Comment: Ну я не так выразился именно php кода, который генерирует эту bmp-строку. Большое спасибо!!

Comment: Аааа, визивиг-редактор картинок для php?) гы, это интересно) 

Теоретически это можно соорудить на флэше и мобыть какой-нибудь фрик этим занялся, но я, если честно, сомневаюсь, хотя поискать можно)

Comment: А почему фрик то? Программа была бы хорошая, я бы сам даже сделал, но я не достаточно хорошо знаю библиотеку GD и флеш) А вообще по-английски как могут такую прогу назвать?) Можно на зарубежных посмотреть)

Comment: подозреваю, вопрошающий хочет сохранять векторные изображения в готовый php код, который бы их отрисовывал.

@mctrane изобретаем формат svg?